# Попытка подключения фона в CSS

Tags: css, url, img, background-image

пытаюсь в который раз, с помощью свойства CSS - "background-image" задать относительный путь к картинке. С проектом работаю через SublimeText3, создал новый файл css, и новый html - файл, с названиями: "master.css" и "maket.html" Их расположение в корневой папке следующее: [image: Расположение файла master.css]
[image: Расположение картинок в папке проекта]

Чтобы подключить фон на сайте, (подгрузить картинку), я использую следующий путь: url(../img2/ultra_neon.png);[image: Указание url, для подключения]

Comment: Если у вас сервер для разработки, то вам нужно поместить картинки в папку которая будет доступна серверу и настроить его соответствующим образом. Это называется статические файлы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Путь не тот. Файл css подключается к html файлу в корне (maket.html). От него и надо задавать путь:

```css
url("./assets/img2/ultra_neon.png");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал применить ваш путь, однако после внесения изменений, фон всё равно не отобразился на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Вот структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

В файле со стилями style.css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/image.jpg");
}
```

Так же советую посмотреть как у тебя подключены стили в файле index.html

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='assets/css/style.css'>
```